# How to stop listening for fetching chat messages when users sign out in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm building mobile chat application with firebase real-time database and react native.
This application is always listening to fetch new chat messages from firebase database.

But I see the following error message when I click `sign out` button on chat screen because the application in the background always tries to fetch new messages even I have signed out and I don't have a role to read and write chat messages.

This is the error message.

```
console.error: "Uncaught Error in onSnapshot:", {"code": "permission-denied", "name": "FirebaseError" }
```

This is my code for listening to fetch the new chat messages.

```
:
this.firebase.firestore.collection("chat").doc(" chatId").collection("messages")
          .where('counter', '>', this_.messageCounter - Const.chatPagingMessageCount).orderBy('counter', 'asc')
          .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
:
```

I would like to make users sign out without that error.

Comment: are you using redux & react-native-firebase ?

Comment: @Hazim Ali
No, I'm not using both, I use just firebase module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove listener when user left from chat. You can use componentWillUnmount lifecycle method or sign out action for that.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

```
componentDidMount () {
  this._listenToMessages();
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  this.chatListener();
}

_listenToMessages = () => {
  this.chatListener = 
    this.firebase.firestore.collection("chat").doc("chatId").collection("messages")
      .where('counter', '>', this_.messageCounter - 
      Const.chatPagingMessageCount).orderBy('counter', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        ...
      }
}
```